# How to migrate over from CRA without using SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, migration, create-react-app

The company I work for is looking to migrate away from CRA since it has been deprecated. Our application is quite extensive, with over 3000 files. I have attempted to use the NextJs code mod for migration. We also directly import CSS files into components from 3rd-party libraries, in addition to some local CSS files, and we also utilize SASS. This is where the main issue arises, as I encounter problems with dynamically importing these CSS/SCSS files. The code mod ended up placing all those files into the global _app.js, but it still isn't functioning correctly. This complexity seems to be growing. Could anyone provide guidance on the best approach for this migration? We are not interested in utilizing SSR. We currently use React Router and intend to stick with it rather than adopting NextJS’s routing. Is there an easier way to migrate without making significant changes?